# How can retrieve the date value of the opportunity history record in reporting?

Tags: reporting, date, analytics

Is there a way to return the date (and time) of the opportunity history record, i.e., when it was saved/created? I am currently unable to build a report of opportunities that have moved to a certain stage in a certain period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reports -> New Report -> Opportunity History Report (NOT Opportunity field history report)

[image]

Opportunity history records only expose Last Modified Date, which is fine because they are read only.

Comment: so Last Modified Date really means the date the record was created. Thanks for that.